# I need to copy the rows from table where it has id column as primary key and id values has random values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table of 500 rows with orderid column as primary key, and the values in are random say 10248,10250,10256,10258...... so on, now I have the code to copy the first 50 rows in a loop of 2, but the orderid column will be incremented by 1, the code is

```
create procedure USP_CopyingDuplicateRows @loop int, @top int
as 
Begin
Declare  @i int = 1,@Maxid int = 0
while(@i <= @loop)
Begin
select @Maxid = max([OrderID]) from [T_MyOrders]
insert into [T_MyOrders]([OrderID],[CustomerID] ,[EmployeeID],[OrderDate],[RequiredDate] ,[ShippedDate] ,[ShipVia],[Freight] ,[ShipName] ,[ShipAddress],[ShipCity] ,[ShipRegion] ,[ShipPostalCode],[ShipCountry] )
select top (@top) @Maxid+(row_number() over( order by [OrderID])) as [OrderID],[CustomerID] ,[EmployeeID],[OrderDate],[RequiredDate] ,[ShippedDate] ,[ShipVia],[Freight] ,[ShipName] ,[ShipAddress],[ShipCity] ,[ShipRegion] ,[ShipPostalCode],[ShipCountry] 
 from T_myorders
set @i=@i+1
END
End
```

But now I want the output as say if the table ends with 10800 as last orderid,  if I copy first 10 rows, then it should give orderid with the gaps of orderid they are in, say first 10 orderid's are 10248,10250,10251,10256,10258.... now the output should be shown as 10801,10803,10804,10808,10810...... In this way the gaps i between orderid's should also be added and displayed in output. Can anyone help in this

Comment: Is there a particular problem you are looking to solve?   I ask, because there might be an easier way to solve it.

Comment: I mean this was the task I was given, and in that way as I shown in my question, I need the output in that way.